# R performing r rbind on dataframes some of which are empty

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a number of dataframes that I want to join together. The problem is that some of these may at times be empty and this produces an error message

eg if df3 is empty

```
rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

gives an error message

> Error: object 'df3' not found

How can I make rbind ignore empty dataframes and only bind the ones that exist.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can load the dataset into a `list` and use `bind_rows`.  The advantage is that only those datasets that are created in the global env gets loaded

```
library(dplyr)
mget(ls(pattern ='^df\\d+$')) %>%
   bind_rows
```

---

Or another option is to create a condition with `exists`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0("df", 1:3), function(x)
          if(exists(x, .GlobalEnv)) get(x) else NULL))
```